# Cómo deshabilitar y habilitar <a>?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy teniendo problemas para habilitar y deshabilitar un link de descarga.
Tengo el script de la siguiente forma:

```
        <script>
        function habilitar(){
            let instagram1 = document.getElementById("instagramb1");
            let instagram2 = document.getElementById("instagramb2");
            let boton = document.getElementById ("freedownloadb");

            console.log(instagram1);
            console.log(instagram2);
            console.log(boton);




            if(instagram1.onclick){
                boton.disable=false;
                console.log(instagram1.onclick)

            }
            else{
                boton.disable=true;
            }


        }
            habilitar();
    </script>
```

El problema es que cuando lo consologueo, sólo toma la función instagram on.click, pero no me devuelve el booleano para que se habilite o deshabilite el link de descarga.

Les dejo también la parte del codigo html.

```
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/town.of.hell" id="instagramb1" target="blank" onclick="instagram" role="button"><img src="assets/icon/IG_ICON.svg" alt="" id="instagram" ></a> //LINK DE INSTAGRAM

  

<a href="https://www.instagram.com/sloth_musik" id="instagramb2" target="blank"  onclick="instagram" role="button"><img src="assets/icon/IG_ICON.svg" alt="" id="instagram"></a>
```

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y8VWNvo2nmSlXtp6H8lTO_oup0HpNfO5?usp=sharing" role="button" disable target="blank" id="freedownloadb"><img src="assets/icon/Iconos_DOWNLOAD-08.svg" alt="" id="freedownload"></a> // LINK DE DESCARGA
```

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para darte unos ejemplos

Comment: Un problema que tienes aqui, es que if(instagram1.onclick) no es una condicion evaluable como tu entiendo estas viendo, no guarda un valor booleano de si fue clickeado, sino que almacena en su interior el codigo a ser ejecutado al ser clicekado, dispara un evento "on click" entiendo que tu intentas ejecutar eso solo cuando se haga click en el boton 1, en ese caso, debes agregar la funcion directamente a ese boton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aca te dejo un pequeño ejemplo con class list toggle, y una clase que desactiva el elemento para que no sea clickeable.

```js
document.getElementById("selector").onclick = () => {
   document.getElementById("link").classList.toggle("disable")
}
```

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<a id="selector" href="#">este es el que lo cambia</a>
<br/>
<a id="link" href="#" class="disable" >este es el link</a>
```

Aca te dejo un ejemplo con Jquery, mas cortito.

```js
$('#selector').click( 
  () => $('#link').toggleClass('disable') 
)
```

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="selector" href="#">este es el que lo cambia</a>
<br/>
<a id="link" href="#" class="disable" >este es el link</a>
```

Comment: Gracias Facu!! me salvaste la vida, muy buena explicación. Ahora, la idea es que por defecto quede desactivado el link, hasta que se clickeé.

Comment: agregale la clase disabled directamente y listo

Comment: ahi lo modifique para que quede

Comment: Sos un crack amigo, me sacaste un dolor de cabeza que tenía desde la mañana, mil gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo!!

Answer (score 1):

Te ofresco una forma según yo más sencilla:

llamas a tu botón:

```
 let boton = document.getElementById ("freedownloadb");
```

y le cambias el href directamente

```
    //"Desactivar" 
    boton.href="#";
    console.log(boton.href);
```

y luego devuelves tu valor

```
    //"Activar" 
    boton.href="link.php";
    console.log(boton.href);
```

---

EDIT:

En una función sería algo asi:

**PARA ACTIVAR**

```js
function accion(id_boton,tipo,link)
{
    let boton = document.getElementById (id_boton);
  if(tipo=="Activar")
  {
    boton.href=link;
  }
  else
    boton.href="#";
}   


accion("freedownloadb","Activar","hola.com"); //Activar
```

```html
<a href="hola.txt" id="freedownloadb">A</a>
```

**PARA DESACTIVAR**

```js
            
function accion(id_boton,tipo,link)
{
    let boton = document.getElementById (id_boton);
  if(tipo=="Activar")
  {
    boton.href=link;
  }
  else
    boton.href="#";
}   

accion("freedownloadb","Desactivar",""); //Desactivar
```

```html
<a href="hola.txt" id="freedownloadb">A</a>
```

Comment: Así quedó la función, pero no logro activarla. Y tampoco entiendo cómo puede tomar el on.click de los links de instagram, si en ningún momento los declaro.

Comment: Es una funcion la puedes llamar como desees solo colocas **accion(id_del_boton,tipo,ulr)** y listo, lo puedes llamar con un onclick dentro de un boton o directamente como te coloque el ejemplo

Comment: Si no sabes coloca tu codigo aca https://jsfiddle.net/ para asi ver lo que tienes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9j8zn21a/#&togetherjs=RnjkJzbIIK

Comment: Quieres que se active el link cuando haga que?

Comment: cuando se clickee los links de instagram, por eso presenté el código al principio, según mi lógica

Comment: los dos o solo uno?

Comment: ambos links....

Comment: Listo, prueba aca https://jsfiddle.net/0ztaLn2j/ si no haces click en los 2 no muestra el link usando la funcion que te pase

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :(. Me muestra el contador en la consola y funciona bien, pero lo mismo sigue deshabilitado el link de descarga

Comment: Estas en otro link entonces, porque este ultimo que te pase https://jsfiddle.net/0ztaLn2j/ es justo ya lo probe